# starting a Centos 7 VM on AMD laptop running Windows 10 host

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, virtual-machine, centos, amd-ryzen

I have an existing Centos 7 VM that I can start without problems on a Windows 10 desktop (Intel CPU). I recently bought a new (Lenovo) laptop with a Ryzen 7 CPU; also Windows 10. I copied the vdi to the laptop and tried to bring it in using VirtualBox 7.0.8. I get

```
Failed  to access perfctr msr (MSR c0001004 is 0)
```

and then get an "unrecoverable error" screen.
This looks very similar to this previous post [failed to access perfctr msr - When running Fedora on a VM](https://superuser.com/questions/833247/failed-to-access-perfctr-msr-when-running-fedora-on-a-vm)
except that my host OS is Windows 10 and not Ubuntu (so the solution there won't apply).

I repeated the same exact process on a friends laptop (Windows 10 host, same version of VirtualBox, intel CPU). This worked fine! I need to get this to work on my laptop; the only difference that I see is that his is an Intel CPU and mine is Ryzen. I checked that Virtualization is enabled on the Ryzen laptop (I looked at Task Manager / Performance / CPU ).

Any idea why I'm getting this failure and what I can do to fix it?

Comment: Virtualization is enabled on the Ryzen laptop (I looked at Task Manager / Performance / CPU    ..........   You really should open up BIOS and ensure Hardware Virtualization and VT-d are both enabled.

Comment: @John thanks for your suggestion. I entered BIOS and under "Virtualization" only "AMD - V (TM)" showed up; it was enabled already. There were no other settings.

Comment: Maybe ask your PC support site if that setting will run 64-bit machines.  I have not seen just that setting.

Comment: The laptop is a "Thinkpad V". This site shows that "AMD - V" is the only option https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/solutions/ht500006-how-to-enable-virtualization-technology-on-lenovo-computers

Comment: According to the Lenovo site, it should work.   I will look around to see if I can find another reason.

Comment: Look at this article:   https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?t=105364  Make sure Guest Extensions are installed. Make sure not more than 2 CPU. Try 6 GB of memory. Read the accepted solution.

Comment: Guest Extensions is installed; I also tried 2 CPU + 6 GB memory...still no luck. I also checked that MIcrosoft Hyper-V is enabled....

Comment: I will keep watch on this.  You may try removing Hyper-V (Programs and Features, Windows Features.   Restart and test again.

Comment: ok...I really appreciate your effort. BTW I already tried with Hyper-V enabled and disabled; they both failed although with Hyper-V disabled it crashes much sooner in the Centos bootup sequence.

Comment: You may ultimately have to build a new Centos machine on the new Host. I am not sure now if there is any other way.

Comment: that also failed the same way as an existing vdi : centos installs ok but it crashes on startup

Comment: I am unfortunately out of answers. I use VMware Workstation and all my Linux systems (not Centos) start and work properly. Intel CPU.

Comment: You might, as a last ditch attempt, get the Lenovo Driver Update App and update all drivers including BIOS.

Comment: I updated bios and all drivers. I also matched exactly all VirtualBox and Hyper-V settings on the laptop where things worked. Still Centos 7 + AMD crashes on startup. As an experiment I tried Windows 7 guest on  the same AMD laptop; this worked! So the problem seems specific to Centos and Ryzen. Anyway at this point it looks like a dead end...thanks for all your suggestions.